# Moving to the end of the text in a readonly TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, readonly

I currently have a TextBox in my WPF application that is readonly:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_CurrentDirectory" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
```

And text gets updated in the Code Behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var app = Application.Current as App;
    TextBox_CurrentDirectory.Text = app.ActiveDirectory;
    //Show the end of the text here
}
```

Is there a way for me to show the end of the text programmatically? If the text in the TextBox is longer than the TextBox, it only shows the start and gets cut off. I'd like to be able to show the end of the text.

I tried using

```
TextBox_CurrentDirectory.CaretIndex = TextBox_CurrentDirectory.Text.Length;
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your TextBox Focus before setting the `CaretIndex`.

```
TextBox_CurrentDirectory.Text = app.ActiveDirectory;
TextBox_CurrentDirectory.Focus();
TextBox_CurrentDirectory.CaretIndex = TextBox_CurrentDirectory.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed the copy/paste issue. It worked perfectly, thank you so much :)

Comment: I think the OP just wants to show the end of the text without caring about the caret position. So just calling `ScrollToEnd()` is OK, isn't it?

Comment: @KingKing - I thought that too but it didn't work in my test. I think calling `ScrollToEnd` like that may be for multiline textboxes.

Comment: @miguelarcilla - You're welcome :) Just updated the answer. If you set focus before the CaretIndex, you don't need to call ScrollToEnd at all.

Comment: @keyboardP that makes sense, I guess I forgot that you need to be focused on a TextBox for the caret to come into play